# Ember / Handlebars / bootstrap - getting 2 divs per row

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

What is the best way to get N dividers per row in a template while looping over objects in an array? Basically I need something like below, but don't know how many elements are in the array beforehand.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6"> 
      {{ someView }}
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      {{ someView }}
   </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6"> 
      {{ someView }}
   </div>
   <div class="span6">
      {{ someView }}
   </div>
</div>
```

I found [this link](http://jaketrent.com/post/every-nth-item-in-handlebars-loop/), but can't get that to work with the latest versions of Ember and Handlebars. Has anyone done this before?

Comment: Maybe this is a candidate for a custom handlebars helper. If you don't feel like writing it, check [Handlebars Helper](https://github.com/danharper/Handlebars-Helpers) (last commit 7 months ago) and use expressions such as "greater than", "less than or equal" and write a template that renders the way you want; but this approach will potentially make your templates fat and overly complex. I'd write my own custom helpers.

Comment: Well, this fiddle kind of works. If you have any pointers I'd appreciate it! http://jsfiddle.net/reptilicus/D8j2L/